# unity make a delay between switching panels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I currently have such a piece of code in panelmanager where I open certain panels (I have a similar piece of code for closing panels). But I wanted to make sure that after pressing the button, there was no instant switching between panels, but with a delay. I read that it can be done with coroutines, but I haven't succeeded yet, since I'm probably using it incorrectly. Please tell me how I can implement such a delay correctly, I'm a complete noob..

```
public void OpenPanel(string name)
{
    switch (name)
    {
        case nameof(MainMenu):
            StartCoroutine(CoroutineSample());
            MainMenuPanel.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            break;
        case nameof(LevelsPanel):
            StartCoroutine(CoroutineSample());
            LevelsPanel1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            break;
    }
}


private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(CoroutineSample());

}
private IEnumerator CoroutineSample()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the

```
MainMenuPanel.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

inside the coroutine after the `yield return` line.

As it is in your code the `StartCoroutine` just starts the coroutine and then continues immediately with the next line. So it won't wait. And the `WaitForSeconds` call doesn't help anything because after the 2 seconds the coroutine doesn't do anything.

Comment: as far as I understood, I have to do similar actions inside CoroutineSample: closed the panel, waited two seconds, opened a new panel. Right? But is it possible to use coroutines with the current organization of the code? I just can't figure it out..

Comment: @Smth_Unknown you can add parameters to your coroutine calls and do stuff in there. Have you read [the manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)?